# Hosting application on Windows Server running IIS and want to redirect website to application using a port

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I am running [Uptime Kuma](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma) on our server and it's using a port 1234 for instance. I can access the application by going to https://myserver.com:1234 but the certificate is invalid. I'd like to access the application directly on https://myserver.com without the port.

We are running Windows 2022 with IIS 10 on a dedicated cloud server. For SSL certificates I'm using Lets Encrypt.

Two questions:

1. Can I setup IIS/Uptime to bind to my url myserver.com without the port?
2. If I can do the above, can it use the certificate for my website? I'm getting an invalid certificate if I have to append the port at the end.

I tried binding the port in IIS but the website will not start since the port is already in use by Uptime Kuma.

[image]

I wasn't sure how to search for this so any information or links would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot you configure Uptime Kuma to hook to port 443? If not, you might configure IIS/ARR as a reverse proxy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: That port is used by IIS. If I try to bind to that port with Uptime Kuma it gives me this `Cannot listen: listen EACCES: permission denied 111.111.111.111:443`.

Comment: I'll check out the reverse proxy though, thanks for the info!

Comment: I installed "Application Request Routing" per the link and it killed every ssl cert I had installed. I had to uninstall  it and reissue my certs.  I didnt even configure anything, immediately after the installation, all websites stopped working.

Comment: That installer shouldn't have touched any of your certificates as it won't modify the certificate mappings in HTTP API, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Are you sure the mappings were changed after installing ARR? And how did you enroll Let's Encrypt certificates? You didn't reveal much in that area.